# How can I change the icon in Thunderbird's "New Mail" popup?

Tags: icons, thunderbird, notify-osd

When I recieve new mails in `Thunderbird` a popup-message tells me about that. Does anyone know where this icon is stored and how it is named? I want to change it that it fits the Faenza-theme.

[image]

I use Thunderbird 10.0.2 with following addons (all preinstalled):

- EDS Contact Integration 0.3.9
- Global Menu Bar integration 2.0.2
- Messaging Menu and Unity Launcher integration 0.8.3

**Update:**

The Addons don't have any influence on the icon - I checked this by disabling them.

I downloaded the [source code](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/thunderbird/releases/10.0.2/source/thunderbird-10.0.2.source.tar.bz2) and scanned it for the icon. I found it as *comm-release/mail/themes/gnomestripe/mail/icons/new-mail-alert.png*:

[image: new-mail-alert.png]

Since I couldn't find this file (I searched for the name) on my PC I guess it is somehow built into Thunderbird and protected against changes. Or should there be an easy solution (not to built your own deb-file)?

(In the same manner I'd like to change *downloadIcon.png* in `Firefox`: [image: downloadIcon.png])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is located under compressed file named **omni.ja**.You can find it under `/usr/lib/thunderbird` or `/usr/lib/thunderbird{version}`.

[image]

Open terminal.

Type sudo `sudo file-roller /usr/lib/thunderbird/omni.ja`  **# replace the path according to your path.**

Navigate to `/chrome/classic/skin/classic/messenger/icons`. Replace the new-mail-alert icon with whatever you want to.

First copy the faenza icon (default size 32x32) to your desktop.

Rename it to `new-mail-alert.png`.

Then just drag the icon over Archieve manager window. It will automatically overwrite the icon.

Restart thunderbird.

DONE!

---

**For Firefox** you can also find the omni.ja file located under `/usr/lib/firefox`.Navigate to `/chrome/toolkit/skin/classic/mozapps/downloads` & replace the 'downloadicon.png' file.

---

Note: This is weird, because on my computer( running Thinderbird 13 with ubuntu natty & precise) thunderbird uses system theme icons. So you may want to upgrade thunderbird to the latest stable version.

Comment: An upgrade didn't change this, but your answer helps: Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The icon was independent from the icons installed, so I think that it comes with thunderbird or with the plugin for the notify-osd. This is a way to start the searching for it, but I haven't find it.

Comment: Your answer doesn't help me. What is the "way to start the searching for it"? Where should I search for it?